# sass value dependent on parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following react code in my react app, traspiled by webpack/babel:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class world extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>World</h1>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<world/>, document.getElementById('js-app'));
```

However the result is not what I expected, it only renders:

```
<world data-reactroot></world>
```

[image: However the result is not what I expected, it only renders "<world data-reactroot></world>"]

Here is my webpack.config file:

```
var path = require("path"),
    webpack = require("webpack"),
    watchBabel = require("watch-babel"),
    srcJsDir = "assets/js/custom/",
    srcCssDir = "assets/sass/",
    srcDestJsDir = "assets/js/transpiled/",
    options = { glob: "src/*.js" },
    optionsCss = { glob: "src/*.scss" };

module.exports = {

    entry: ["./assets/js/custom/app.js"],
    output: {
        path: "./assets/js/transpiled/",
        filename: "app.es6c.js"
    },
    watch: true,
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 8000
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: ['babel-loader'],
            query: {
                presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"]
            }
        }]
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/')
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

Can you tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use capital-W i.e. `class World extends React.Component`, then `<World />`. In JSX lowercase names are tanslated to DOM nodes (like `<div />`), while capitalized names are resolved to class names.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component : *"Always start component names with a capital letter."*

Comment: smh...*sigh*, Yes its case sensitive, you are both correct, thanks!!!